# How to interrupt my loop calling a function, calling an eventListener calling a function

Tags: javascript

I've made a meteor "game". On window load I set my shield:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("shield").innerHTML = "Max";
  var playStart = document.getElementById("playBtn");
  playStart.addEventListener("click", playGame);
}
```

On a click of the play button I'm calling a function (`playGame`) to loop (currently 20 odd times). In this loop I call my meteor create function (called `setUp`):

```
function playGame() {
  for (i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById("shield").innerHTML != "End") {
      setUp();
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

In setup I create the meteor and animate it. I've added an event listener so that on the animation's end (i.e. the "player" hasn't destroyed the meteor) it calls a function to remove the meteor and change the shield status:

```
function setup() {
  imgMeteor.addEventListener("animationend", imgEnd);

  // This function (imgEnd is within my setUp function).
  function imgEnd() {
    var child = document.getElementById("imgMeteor");
    imgMeteor.parentNode.removeChild(imgMeteor);

    var currShield = document.getElementById("shield").innerHTML;
    switch (currShield) {
      case "Max":
        currShield = "Med";
        break;
      case "Med":
        currShield = "Min";
        break;
      case "Min":
        currShield = "None";
        break;
      case "None":
        currShield = "End";
        break;
    }

    document.getElementById("shield").innerHTML = currShield;
    if (currShield == "End") {
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

(I've tried to show just the relevant code). How can I stop the loop running. (Basically I want the game to end once the barrier is "End"?
Any help would be awesome. Entire code below if that helps.

```
var numText = ["Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
  "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"
];
var modText = ["0", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8", "x9"];

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("shield").innerHTML = "Max";
  var arrNum = 0;
  document.getElementById("spdText").innerHTML = numText[arrNum];
  myNum = arrNum;
  var upSpd = document.getElementById("upBtn");
  upSpd.addEventListener("click", nextyNum);
  var downSpd = document.getElementById("downBtn");
  downSpd.addEventListener("click", prevyNum);
  var playStart = document.getElementById("playBtn");
  playStart.addEventListener("click", playGame);
  var playPause = document.getElementById("pauseBtn");
  playPause.addEventListener("click", pauseGame);
}

function nextyNum() {
  myNum += 1;
  if (myNum <= 9) {
    document.getElementById("spdText").innerHTML = numText[myNum];
    document.getElementById("warpProg").value = [myNum];
    document.getElementById("currMod").innerHTML = modText[myNum]
  } else {
    alert("She cannie take any more cap'n. Speed's at maximum");
  }
  if (myNum > 9) {
    myNum = 9;
  }
  progColourCheck();
}

function prevyNum() {
  myNum -= 1;
  if (myNum >= 0) {
    document.getElementById("spdText").innerHTML = numText[myNum];
    document.getElementById("warpProg").value = [myNum];
    document.getElementById("currMod").innerHTML = modText[myNum];
  } else {
    alert("She's as low as she can go cap'n ");
  }
  if (myNum < 0) {
    myNum = 0;
  }
  progColourCheck();
}

function progColourCheck() {
  var progColours = ["lightgrey", "lightyellow", "yellow", "greenyellow", "lawngreen", "#73e600",
    "#cc9900", "orange", "orangered", "red"
  ];
  document.getElementById("warpProg").style.color = progColours[myNum];
  document.getElementById("currMod").style.backgroundColor = progColours[myNum];
}

function playGame() {
  var tempScore = document.getElementById(currScore);
  tempScore = parseInt(currScore.innerHTML);
  var hiScore = document.getElementById(hScore);
  hiScore = parseInt(hScore.innerHTML);
  if (tempScore > hiScore) {
    hScore.innerHTML = tempScore;
  }
  currScore.innerHTML = 0000;
  if (myNum == 0) {
    alert("The ship's not movin' cap'n");
    return;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById("shield").innerHTML != "End") {
      document.getElementById("upBtn").disabled = "true";
      document.getElementById("downBtn").disabled = "true";
      setUp();
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("titleText").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("playBtn").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function setUp() {
  var imgMeteor = document.createElement("p");
  var blankNode = document.createTextNode("");
  imgMeteor.appendChild(blankNode);
  document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild(imgMeteor);
  imgMeteor.style.visibility = "hidden";
  imgMeteor.style.backgroundImage = 'url("meteor.gif")';
  imgMeteor.style.width = "56px";
  imgMeteor.style.height = "56px";
  imgMeteor.style.position = "absolute";
  imgMeteor.addEventListener("mouseover", removeElement);
  imgMeteor.style.animationName = "animBlock";
  imgMeteor.style.animationDuration = 10 - myNum + "s";
  imgMeteor.style.animationDelay = Math.floor(Math.random() * (8 - 0 + 1)) + 0 + "s";
  imgMeteor.style.animationTimingFunction = "linear";
  imgMeteor.addEventListener("animationstart", imgVis);

  function imgVis() {
    imgMeteor.style.visibility = "visible";
  }

  imgMeteor.addEventListener("animationend", imgEnd);
  var leftPos = xPosition(0);
  imgMeteor.style.left = leftPos + "%";
  var topPos = yPosition(0);
  imgMeteor.style.top = topPos + "px";

  function removeElement() {
    var cScore = document.getElementById("CurrScore");
    cScore = parseInt(currScore.innerHTML);
    cScore += (1 * myNum);
    currScore.innerHTML = cScore;
    var child = document.getElementById("imgMeteor");
    imgMeteor.parentNode.removeChild(imgMeteor);
    document.getElementById("barrier").style.background = "linear-gradient(darkblue, lightblue)";
  }

  function imgEnd() {
    var child = document.getElementById("imgMeteor");
    imgMeteor.parentNode.removeChild(imgMeteor);
    document.getElementById("barrier").style.background = "linear-gradient(red, orange)";
    var cScore = document.getElementById("CurrScore");
    cScore = parseInt(currScore.innerHTML);
    var negScore = myNum;
    if (negScore > 1) {
      negScore -= 1;
    }
    cScore -= (1 * negScore);
    currScore.innerHTML = cScore;

    var currShield = document.getElementById("shield").innerHTML;
    switch (currShield) {
      case "Max":
        currShield = "Med";
        break;
      case "Med":
        currShield = "Min";
        break;
      case "Min":
        currShield = "None";
        document.getElementById("bubble").style.visibility = "hidden";
        break;
      case "None":
        currShield = "End";
        break;
    }
    document.getElementById("shield").innerHTML = currShield;
    if (currShield == "End") {
      return;
    }
  }
}

function xPosition(lPos) {
  var lPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (90 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  return lPos;
}

function yPosition(tPos) {
  var tPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (80 - 10 + 1)) + 10;
  return tPos;
}

function pauseGame() {
  playBtn.style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById("upBtn").disabled = "false";
  document.getElementById("downBtn").disabled = "false";
  document.getElementById("shield").innerHTML = "Max";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should look like this then:

```
function playGame() {
    for (i=0; i < 21; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById("shield").innerHTML == "End"){
            break;
       }
       SetUp();
    }
}
```

You want to `break` the loop when the condition is met.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried this but the meteors still seem to complete their loop. For some reson it thinks the shield.innerHTML is "Max" despite it changing the text onscreen correctly.

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with id "shield"? If this is the case, you should then change your logic. In HTML each element should have its own unique id.

Comment: I've checked the HTML and there is only the one paragraph with an id of shield. It's weird. I've checked where the element's innerHTML is updated (in the function that is called on each animations end) and that bit is working - its updating the field but when I see what the element's inner html is before the for statement above it always says "Max" (the value on load.). It's as if its somehow not updated it at the point its checking it. yet I'm writing to and from the same value (see javascript above) - the shield's innerHTML.